# Wep API to take multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to web api. I created a sample web api and it works fine to return all data from a table and by Id. Right now I am trying to create a function to take multiple parameters but I get errors with "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". Below is my code and I have no clue where the problem is:

```
enter code here
// GET: api/Biosample
// http://localhost:53205/api/Biosample/example1/catalognbr/campusstr/
        [Route("example1/{catalognbr}/{campusstr}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<Biosample> GetBiosample(float catalognbr, string campusstr)
        {

                var Biosample= (from a in db.Biosample
                                  where a.CATALOG_NBR  == catalognbr &&
                                        a.CAMPUS_NAME.Contains(campusstr)

                                       select a
                                  );

            return Biosample;
            }
```

Comment: Please provide how are you making the call.

Comment: http://localhost:53205/api/Biosample/example1/catalognbr/campusstr/